# Insert key on external UK Apple keyboard

Tags: keyboard, vmware-fusion

I am using an external Apple keyboard and using Windows 7 in VMWare Fusion.

One of my Windows apps responds to the Insert key.  How do I simulate pressing insert on the Apple keyboard ?

I have searched around and the common response is to use the Help key, only my keyboard has no Help key.

Comment: Please accept your answer as this'll prevent your question from being bumped to the front page again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found one !

On the numeric keypad, the key for zero sometimes acts like the insert key.  This is toggled by another key on the numeric keypad - the one containing the picture of a box with a diagonal cross through it (the numlock key ?).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remap keys under Windows, I recommend [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/).