# How do I pass Insert key to Windows 7 under VMWare Fusion 4.0?

Tags: vmware-fusion

My iMac has an external mini wireless keyboard (so identical to Macbooks) and I need to pass the Insert key to the virtual machine running windows 7 under VMWare Fusion 4.1. Lots of web advice that doesn't work under v4.1, including [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/193988/insert-key-on-external-uk-apple-keyboard) on superuser.

Doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key in the Settings for your [vmware-fusion](/questions/tagged/vmware-fusion) virtual machine.

1. Open the Settings for your VM. (Not Fusion's Preferences).
2. Click Keyboard & Mouse.
   [image: Click Keyboard & Mouse]
3. Select the Default profile.
4. Select Edit Profile from the drop down.
   [image: Click Edit Profile]
5. Click the + button.
   [image: Click the + button]
6. Click in the top box and press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>. `Num Pad Enter` should appear in the box.
7. In the bottom box select `Insert` from the drop down list.
   [image: Setup the Num Pad Enter as the Insert key]
8. Press Ok and close the Settings window.

You can now use the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key by pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> just like in [bootcamp](/questions/tagged/bootcamp).